# Convert day of the year to datetime in php

Tags: php, datetime

I have value

```
$days = 166.0444;
```

which is day of the year. How can I simply convert this value to its datetime, which should be

```
2013-06-15 01:04:ss
```

? Of course I can subtract number of days in month to get month, then proceed with days and so on, but is there some other way?

Edit: Year would be always current year

Thank you, everyone, this is how I did it:

```
$dayOfYear = (int)$result;
$temp =  ($result - $dayOfYear) * 24;
$hours = (int)$temp;
$temp = ($temp - $hours) * 60;
$minutes = (int)$temp;
$temp = ($temp - $minutes) * 60;
$seconds = (int)$temp;

$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P' . $dayOfYear . 'D'));
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $hours . 'H'));
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes . 'M'));
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $seconds . 'S'));
```

Comment: as long as you don't know the actual year, this is unachievable. datetime needs at least a year to work and you need to tell whether February has 28 or 29 days.

Comment: Year would be always current year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this or similar way:

```
function convertDaysToDateTime($days, $year){
    $datetime = new DateTime();
    return $datetime->setTimestamp(mktime(0,0,0,0,0,$year) + $days * 24 * 3600);
}

$days = 166.0444;       
$datetime = convertDaysToDateTime($days, date('Y'));

echo $datetime->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

If its the current year, you can

```
$days = 166.0444;
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setDate($date->format('Y'), 1, 1);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P' . floor($days) . 'D'));
```